# yourkit cpu view and top command - showing different results

Tags: profiling, profiler, yourkit

I am looking at my process via **top** command and it shows very high value on the CPU%. however when I look on the same process via yourkit cpu view it shows completely different result. how can it be ?
[image: top command]

[image: yourkit cpu view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YourKit profiler treats entire CPU with all cores as 100%. It means that if you have 4 cores and 1 core is fully loaded and other 3 cores sleep, then CPU usage will be 25% (not 100%).

After this explanation YourKit results correlate good with "top".

Answer (score 0):

Even I have the same confusion. From what I understand top command displays as a percentage of a single CPU. On multi-core systems, you can have percentages that are greater than 100%
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145247/understanding-cpu-while-running-top-command

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, he is asking about the reason of the difference between two results.